# Slow SQL INNER JOIN

Tags: mysql, join, indexing

I'm performing sql requests on table `interim_19` with 67.500 rows. Table is not indexed, and has 7 columns, non of which are unique/primary keys, because main data `Abonent` and `idBase` are repeating, among all data I have like 7-8 distinct `idBases` and ~10.000 different `Abonents`, and the other data like `date`  is not reliable in terms of uniqueness.

**The problem is in slow inner joins on this table.**

And if I perform `SELECT * FROM interim_19 WHERE idBase IN (1551 , 42286 )` it'll take 1.33 seconds, and `SELECT * FROM interim_19 WHERE idBase IN (1535 , 5406 )` will take 1.9 seconds, whether

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM interim_19 WHERE idBase IN (1551 , 42286 )) 
temp1 
inner join 
(SELECT * FROM interim_19 WHERE idBase IN (1535 , 5406 )) temp2 
on temp1.Abonent = temp2.Abonent
```

takes forever - 147-157 seconds. I understand that inner join does compare every row to every other row on second table, but this shouldn't take this long. OFC it makes duplicates, but I need all 7+7 rows, so...

P.S I'm already trying to index it, so other advices are also welcome.

Comment: I'm not seeing a reason for the derived tables and joins the tables directly. Also, select only the columns you actually need. "SELECT *" isn't doing you any favors.

Comment: Is it mySql or SQL Server ? Please edit your tags

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the 'composite' `INDEX(idBase, Abonent)`

(And, as others point out, use a `JOIN`, not a subquery.)

An `INDEX` does not need to be "unique".

147 seconds was because the subqueries were performed *many* times, each time looking at 67K rows.  I think my index, above, will help all the queries mentioned so far.

Comment: Thank you, adding index on two items improved it from 147 sec to 0.8.

Answer (score 4):

Try eliminating those unnecessary subqueries:

```
SELECT *
FROM interim_19 t1
INNER JOIN interim_19 t2
    ON t1.Abonent = t2.Abonent
WHERE
    t1.idBase IN (1551 , 4228) AND
    t2.idBase IN (1535 , 5406)
```

Beyond this, you could consider adding an index on the `idBase` column.  And as suggested in the comments, you could also try narrowing down your select list.

Comment: what if i got another idBase to compare, how I add another inner join here?

Comment: If you have another question, then you might want to ask a new question rather than changing your current one.

Comment: NO, I mean, I want to add another join to this query. Should it be: 

`SELECT * FROM interim_19 t1 INNER JOIN interim_19 t2 ON t1.Abonent = t2.Abonent INNER JOIN interim_19 t3 ON t3.Abonent = t2.Abonent WHERE t1.idBase IN (1551 , 4228) AND t2.idBase IN (1535 , 5406) AND t3.idBase IN (29551618)`

Answer (score 3):

Subqueries have no indexes. Try to avoid them as long as it is possible :

```
SELECT *
FROM interim_19 t1
INNER JOIN interim_19 t2
    ON (t1.Abonent = t2.Abonent AND t2.idBase IN (1535 , 5406))
WHERE
    t1.idBase IN (1551 , 4228)
```

Will be a bit faster than Tim's answer...

Comment: what if i got another idBase to compare, how I add another inner join here?